# Function to extract the size in a list

Tags: list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BEdA.png)

I am looking to extract the "size" of the value in the list.
How do I use a function to call for the "Size" of a value? Looking for a function that calls out the size instead of looping the occurrence.